# String get text at the end of line

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, bufferedreader

I have a .txt file that contains a text like:

`blah blah blah size: 80`

`blah blah blah blah size: 150`

Aka there is some text, then a `size:`, `space`, an `int`, `new line`, repeat... Now, I need to get that integer and store it to a variable. I use a BufferedReader that reads the text line by line and everything is normal, but, just because the length of that integer varies, I can't tell for example:

```
String x = line.substring(line.indexOf("size") + 6, line.indexOf("size") + 8)
```

because if size has 3 digits, it will only get the first two of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: so don't use fixed offsets. scan the string backwards for the first space encountered, then use that as the starting point for extracting your digits.

Comment: why don't you split the line on the ":" character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `String#substring(beginIndex)` method which would get the substring starting at the specified index until the end of the string:

```
String x = line.substring(line.indexOf("size") + 6);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is [very false](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Comment: @snickers10m I'm using only one parameter which is the begin index. The link you provided is for a different signature.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were stating that your example was the _only_ option.

Comment: No worries. I updated the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

How about using position of last space to determine from where to substring?

```
String s = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the string and access the last element

```
String[] split = s.split(":");
System.out.println(split[1].trim());
//                       ^-this is just an example, as an exercise try 
//                         to figure out index of last element yourself
```

Comment: this is what I suggested , didn't want to do the work for him...never learn anything that way!

Comment: @SuncoastOwner This is the first approach that came into my mind as well. I wonder why OP is not using this approach and relying on whitespace index?

Answer (score 1):

You can try regex, expression below gets the group of digit:

```
// can run in a for loop for each line
String regEx = ".*size:\s+(\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line); // line to match
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String sizeVal = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the substring after the colon

```
String x = line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 2);
```